# Error creating a new Tensor: Inferred shape does not match provided shape (TensorFlowJS)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, audio, tensorflow.js

I am creating a machine learning model that can tell the difference in audio between a musical instrument and normal conversation. I used a tutorial from [tensorflow.org](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-audio-codelab/index.html#0) that trains the model with live microphone data. I would like to train my model on pre-recorded data, so I modified the code to use an audio file instead. This is working fine up until it tries to train the tensor with the data.

I'm trying to create a new tensor for training, and I'm getting an error related to shape mismatch. The expected shape is (2,1000,192,1), but the inferred shape is (3000,128). I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm preparing the input data or with the training logic.

When switching to pre-recorded audio files, I had to adjust the shape of the tensor to fit the recorded file. In the array with the spectogram data, I add multiple arrays of zeros at the end to fill the space. But, it was adding 16 too many values, and causes a shape mismatch. I fixed this by removing the last 16 values.

This is my training code:

```js
    const NUM_FRAMES = 1000;
    const INPUT_SHAPE = [NUM_FRAMES, 192, 1];

    async function train() {
        if (examples.length) {
            toggleButtons(false);
            const ys = tf.oneHot(examples.map(e => e.label), 2);
            const xsShape = [examples.length, ...INPUT_SHAPE];
            const xs = tf.tensor(flatten(examples.map(e => e.vals)), xsShape);

            await model.fit(xs, ys, {
                batchSize: 16,
                epochs: 10,
                callbacks: {
                    onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => {
                        document.querySelector('#console').textContent =
                            `Accuracy: ${(logs.acc * 100).toFixed(1)}% Epoch: ${epoch + 1}`;
                    }
                }
            });
            tf.dispose([xs, ys]);
            toggleButtons(true);
        }
    }

    function flatten(tensors) {
        const maxSize = INPUT_SHAPE[0] * INPUT_SHAPE[1] * INPUT_SHAPE[2] * tensors.length;
        console.log(maxSize);
        let result = tensors.reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr), []);
        if (result.length * 128 < maxSize) {
            let i = 1;
            let length = Math.floor((maxSize - (result.length * 128)) / 128);
            console.log(length);
            while (i < length) {
                const filler128 = Array(128).fill(0);
                result.push(filler128);
                i++;
            }
            const filler = Array(maxSize - (result.length * 128)).fill(0);
            result.push(filler);
        }
        result[result.length - 1].slice(0, -16);
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
```

This makes the shape of the array the correct size, but doesn't work as expected when it tries to train it. How can I fix it so that the expected shape is the same as the inputed shaped?